# Date range using Advanced Filter

Tags: excel, filter, excel-2007

I currently am using an advanced filter to pull data from a master list. I only have one column for the date in the master list. What I want to do is be able to enter a date range (1/1/11 - 1/31/11) and have the filter only pull the month of January out of all of the data.

Is this possible to do when I only have one column to type in my filter arguments?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a calculated column and use that as an additional filter.

For instance in a new column type in

```
=IIF(MyDate < '2/1/2011 AND MyDate >= '1/1/2011', 1, 0)
```

Then the value of the cell will either be a 1 or 0.  Then just filter your sheet for 1's based on this column.

Answer (score 0):

This solution also requires a new calculated column.  If your dates are (for example) in column E, then put this formula in a new column:

=month(E1)

Copy and paste the formula.  Now you can filter by month.